# Why code doesnt work after handlerCall in .then of fetch in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, fetch, setstate

I am implementing a time log calculator using JIRA API. Why my code does not work after the callHandler in (.then) of (.fetch) in React-Native? Below in the code i'm trying to console.log("HIIIIIIIIIIII"), and trying to setState above that and also debugger, all of them NOT WORKING,neither give any error nor they work, all the lines below the handleJSONData not working though control goes into handleJSONData, why is this happening?? Any other way to use setState to set the state of the progress in the program and where?

Thank you for the help.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated} from 'react-native';
import Button from './Button';
import CardSection from './CardSection';
import MyDatePicker from "./MyDatePicker";
import Card from "./Card";
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";


const handleStartDate = (delta) => {
    return (previousState, currentProps) => {
        return {...previousState, startDate: delta};
    };
};

const handleEndDate = (delta) => {
    return (previousState, currentProps) => {
        return {...previousState, endDate: delta};
    };
};

const handleProgressUpdate = () => {
    return (previousState, currentProps) => {
        return {...previousState, progress: this.state.dictionary["jatinverma"]};
    };
};

class AppComp extends Component {
    state = {startDate: null, endDate: null, jiraData: "", progress: 0, dictionary: {}};

    onStartDateChange = (date) => {
        this.setState(handleStartDate(date));
    };

    onEndDateChange = (date) => {
        this.setState(handleEndDate(date));
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        // debugger;
    }

    handleJSONData = (data) => {
        var keyArr = Object.keys(this.state.dictionary);

        for (var i = 0; i <= data.issues.length; i++) {

            fetch(data.issues[i].self, {
                method: 'get',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
                }
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(resData => {
                    var worklogsArr = resData.fields.worklog.worklogs;

                    for (var j = 0; j < worklogsArr.length; j++) {

                        var dtc = +Date.parse(worklogsArr[j].updated.slice(0, 10));
                        var startDate = +Date.parse(this.state.startDate);
                        var endDate = +Date.parse(this.state.endDate);
                        if ((dtc >= startDate) && (dtc <= endDate)) {
                            if (Object.keys(this.state.dictionary).indexOf(worklogsArr[j].author.name) >= 0) {
                                var nameDic = worklogsArr[j].author.name;
                                var abc = this.state.dictionary;
                                var ov = this.state.dictionary[nameDic];

                                abc[nameDic] = ov + worklogsArr[j].timeSpentSeconds;
                                this.setState({dictionary: abc});
                                console.log(this.state)
                            } else {
                                var nameDic = worklogsArr[j].author.name;
                                var abc = this.state.dictionary;

                                abc[nameDic] = worklogsArr[j].timeSpentSeconds;
                                this.setState({dictionary: abc});
                                console.log(this.state);
                            }
                        } else {

                        }

                    }
                });
        }

    }

    handleButtonClick = () => {
        this.setState({dictionary: {}});

        if (!global.btoa) {
            global.btoa = require('base-64').encode;
        }

        fetch('https://crossitc.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=updated>=' + this.state.startDate + '%20AND%20updated<=' + this.state.endDate, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                console.log(responseData);
                this.handleJSONData(responseData);

                 this.setState(handleProgressUpdate);
                console.log("HIIIIIIIIIIII" + this.state);
                debugger;
            });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <MyDatePicker onDateChangeRef={this.onStartDateChange} dateDateRef={this.state.startDate}/>
                    <Text> START={this.state.startDate}</Text>
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <MyDatePicker onDateChangeRef={this.onEndDateChange} dateDate={this.state.endDate}/>
                    <Text> END={this.state.endDate}</Text>
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Button onPress={this.handleButtonClick}>CLICK!!!</Button>
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
                            <Text>Hours:</Text>
                            <ProgressBar progress={this.state.progress} row duration={500}/>
                            <Text>100%</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>

        );
    }
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    progressContainer: {
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "row"
    }
}

export default AppComp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't chained a `.catch()` statement to your Promise, so naturally you won't see any errors in the console.

```
handleButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({dictionary: {}});

    if (!global.btoa) {
        global.btoa = require('base-64').encode;
    }

    fetch('https://crossitc.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=updated>=' + this.state.startDate + '%20AND%20updated<=' + this.state.endDate, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
        }
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
            console.log(responseData);
            this.handleJSONData(responseData);

             this.setState(handleProgressUpdate);
            console.log("HIIIIIIIIIIII" + this.state);
            debugger;
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
}
```

Similarly, I would recommend adding the following line to your top level JavaScript file:

`GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;`

This will allow you to see Network requests in the developer tools, you will then be able to see requests/responses for every API call you make.